Should we add a Classical (and/or Literary) Chinese resource section to "Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese"?
The current central resource question is focussed on Modern Chinese. Should we add a Literary and/or Classical Chinese section?
Alternatively, should we just add a link to the current Classical Chinese resource question (which is quite small, but not in a Wiki format)?
(There is an even smaller question as well.)

It's hard to say what's going to happen with the resources post What's the future for the "Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese" page? and resources in general Are requests for resources on-topic?.  I personally think it's time for the resources page to be "retired" (it's very old), in the sense of being locked (and maybe start a newer one with a better format).  In any case, I don't have a problem with adding a classical Chinese section to it.

absolutely no
mandarin is just a dialect / spoken language, nothing more. classical / literary chinese is a written language.
that, adding classical / literary chinese resource to “resources for learning mandarin chinese” is an significant error in classification.
in the past, there’re japaneses, koreans, or jesuits priests; though they didn’t speak any dialects of chinese, they can read and write classical / literary chinese. indeed, some of them are quite good 

Makes sense.  Maybe Canto Dict should be removed too, then.  (Oh and Wengu.)

@becky , language has 4 aspects: reading, speaking, listening & writing (讀講聽寫). so, i would suggest the next version of resources page, develops upon these aspects.

@ 水巷孑蠻 I see your point. I do think we should have a resource section somewhere for Classical/Literary Chinese specifically (or a link to another site that lists some, such as the reddit site for classical chinese), though.
